# Is this feature redundant?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Say I have a data set, and there's one feature that divides the set into roughly two halves, labeling one half A, and the other half B. Now I have another feature, it labels all instances that were labeled A as 0, and then within B it distinguishes between instances as 1,2,3, etc. Is my first feature (that divides the set into A and B) redundant? If it is, how come I'm getting higher accuracy on models when I use it?

Comment: How were these features generated? What are the models you refer at? How exactly do you test their accuracy?  Sorry to sound somewhat pedantic but you went from an abstraction ("Say I have....") to something very specific ("higher accuracy") a bit abruptly.

Comment: The most important question is the model you're using. Logically, the first feature gives no extra information on top of the second feature, but that doesn't at all mean that models won't do better with that as a feature, depending on the model.

Comment: It actually seems to do better regardless of model (e.g., LibSVM, decision trees, random forest, etc.). There's an increase in accuracy in every model I've tried it on.

Answer (score 0):

In RF, say for example, variables are *selected* to make weak learners. So it is better than nothing to prepare the first variable to achieve higher accuracy -- when the second variable is absent, the model can still perform rough prediction based on the first variable (when the third identical to the first is given, the model may get more *accurate*). But as you can see, the first one is redundant. Refer redundancy analysis (RDA) to control this innate problem.